# AlertDialog not showing on Stepper Fragment

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I'm implementing a Stepper using Android Material Stepper lib (https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper). On the third Step, I'm implementing a BlockingStep to make a Http call while the UI is blocked/showing a Dialog.

The problem is that the Dialog doesn't show up. I tried with ProgressDialog and AlertDialog, but none of them appears on screen.

```
@Override
public void onNextClicked(final StepperLayout.OnNextClickedCallback callback) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_loader);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Generating JSONObject

                //Using AsyncTask to end JSON
                TCPConfigurationTask task = new TCPConfigurationTask();
                String[] params = {mIp, mPort, configObject.toString(), "true"};
                String response = task.execute(params).get();

                //Consuming response
                if (response != null) {
                    Log.d("JSON_CODE_RESPONSE", response);
                }
            } catch (JSONException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                jsonError = true;
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            callback.goToNextStep();
        }
    }, 0L);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Code provided in answer is fine. The problem is that the MainThread was doing too much work waiting for the AsyncTask to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line,

```
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
```

to

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Use below to dismiss dialog,

```
alert.dismiss();
```

Use this, to set custom layout in your AlertDialog,

```
builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_loader);
```

to

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. dialog_loader, null);
builder.setView(dialogView);
```

Comment: exactly my thoughts

Comment: I need to keep the AlertDialog as final, so I can dismiss it when the Thread is done.

Comment: Yes, Thats I saying that, you can dismiss alertdialog in thread using dismiss

Comment: Got it. Tried that, but it's not working yet. The Thread completes, but no Dialog is showing.

Comment: Didn't work again, but your code is not the problem: MainThread was doing too much work because of the `String response = task.execute(params).get();` line. My initial code works, just like both of yours! I'll accept your answer if you add my note, so people can track the problem!

Comment: add my note, means ?

Comment: @NarendraSorathiya "MainThread was doing too much work because of the String response = task.execute(params).get(); line."